# Computation on a Tensor as numpy array in graph?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

Is there any way to do some computation on a tensor in graph.

Example my graph:

```
slim = tf.contrib.slim

def slim_graph(images, train=False):
    with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
                  activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                  weights_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 0.01),
                  weights_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(0.0005)):
        net = slim.repeat(images, 2, slim.conv2d, 64, [3, 3], scope='conv1')
        // Do my compute by numpy on net

        np_array_result = my_func(net)

        // It will return a numpy array
        // Use numpy array as input of graph

        net = slim.max_pool2d(np_array_result, [2, 2], scope='pool1')

        ...
        return logits
```

- Can we do somethings like that?
- How to get feature maps in graph to compute?

I can separate graph into 2 parts and use Session.run([part1])
After that use the result to input my function, then feed it to Session.run([part2])

But it seems weird.

Comment: yes, separating into 2 parts like you showed is the way to do it

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : When i do forward net, it seems okay.
How we run loss function and gradients when do training step? Just calculate losses after get result of part2 and apply gradients on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/script_ops.html#py_func) wrapper for python functions.